# Node.js bundle file with webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I follow the step of a quickstart (Azure Communication service).

I installed node.js and webpack on the server.

I have an index.js file containing the node.js script and now I want to be able to use it from an html page calling a js file (main.js).

package.json :

```
{
  "name": "call",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/communication-calling": "^1.22.2",
    "@azure/communication-common": "^2.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^11.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.90.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js :

```
const path = require('path');
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './index.js',
    target: 'web',
    output: {
        filename: './main.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    devServer: {
        static: {
            directory: path.join(__dirname, './')
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        new CopyPlugin({
            patterns: [
                './index.php'
            ]
        }),
    ]
};
```

On server (SSH) I execute this command :

```
npx webpack serve --config webpack.config.js
```

Answer :

```
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Project is running at:
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Loopback: http://localhost:8080/
<i> [webpack-dev-server] On Your Network (IPv4): http://XX.XX.XXX.XXX:8080/
<i> [webpack-dev-server] On Your Network (IPv6): http://[X::X:X:X:X]:8080/
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Content not from webpack is served from '/home/clients/XXX/XXX/azure-CS/CALL/' directory
asset ./main.js 4.21 MiB [emitted] (name: main)
asset index.php 1.66 KiB [emitted] [from: index.php] [copied]
orphan modules 108 KiB [orphan] 58 modules
runtime modules 27.4 KiB 12 modules
cacheable modules 4.05 MiB
  modules by path ./node_modules/@azure/ 3.86 MiB 26 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/ 71.8 KiB 16 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/webpack/hot/*.js 5.18 KiB
    ./node_modules/webpack/hot/dev-server.js 1.94 KiB [built] [code generated]
    + 3 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/html-entities/lib/*.js 81.8 KiB
    ./node_modules/html-entities/lib/index.js 7.91 KiB [built] [code generated]
    + 3 modules
  ./index.js 13.2 KiB [built] [code generated]
  ./node_modules/ansi-html-community/index.js 4.16 KiB [built] [code generated]
  ./node_modules/events/events.js 14.5 KiB [built] [code generated]
  ./node_modules/jwt-decode/build/esm/index.js 1.66 KiB [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.90.3 compiled successfully in 3460 ms
Watchpack Error (watcher): Error: EACCES: permission denied, watch '/home/clients'
Watchpack Error (watcher): Error: EACCES: permission denied, watch '/home'
Watchpack Error (watcher): Error: EACCES: permission denied, watch '/'
Watchpack Error (initial scan): Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/home/clients'
Watchpack Error (initial scan): Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/home'
Watchpack Error (initial scan): Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/'
assets by status 4.21 MiB [cached] 2 assets
cached modules 4.16 MiB (javascript) 27.4 KiB (runtime) [cached] 124 modules
webpack 5.90.3 compiled successfully in 42 ms
```

a main.js file should be created so that I can call it from my html page, right?

I don't understand why this main.js file is not created.